# Which Facebook SDK should I choose if I want to implement a web app like this one ( http://youarewhatyoulike.com)

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, web

I am new to web development.
And I haven't learnt PHP or JavaScript.
For my final year project, I need to implement a web app like this (http://youarewhatyoulike.com).
Can anyone give me some idea of which Facebook SDK should I choose?
Many thanks!

Comment: start here https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: Use the SDK associated to the programming language you are going to use.